# A man using one finger

Tags: riddle

> A man using only one finger sends up 6 people in 6 seconds.
>
> Is he Superman? No.
>
> Is he Spiderman? No.
>
> Is he Rajnikanth? No.

Who is he?

Comment: I was intrigued by the title, but found this post to be disappointingly SFW.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is he

> A lift-man(elevator-operator) (as in he uses his finger to click on floor number button)

Comment: Why sending up alone? The person whom you have mentioned can also send the persons down right?

Comment: yes, actually, also more than 6 people can fit in the elevator!(Unless this is not the correct answer)

Comment: Also it may take more than 6 seconds for the elevator to get closed after the button has been pressed.

Comment: Quick and correct, And Sends up i have used only to create confusion. Otherwise It'd have become easy one.

Comment: : ) yeah! I figured

Comment: remember to put this answer as the correct one

Comment: I was expecting something more Star-Trek themed, but same concept.

Answer (score 10):

This could be ...

> ... the pilot of a NASA rocket, pressing the ignition?

Comment: Ah yes, spoilers. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

This can be

> The King pointing out people or soldiers to a direction can send more then 6 people and yes 6 people too.

Other thought

> And yeah commander/warlord on the battle field pointing soldiers towards enemy.

Note: They would not require to press any sort of buttons too :)